# VeraCrypt OS X will not accept admin password

Tags: mac, permissions, administrator, veracrypt

I have VeraCrypt v1.23 (the latest version) installed on macOS Mojave v10.14.3 (which I just upgraded). Whenever I either a) click "Selected Device..." or b) click "Mount All Devices" and then enter the VeraCrypt Volume Password, I am presented with a popup that says, `Administrator privileges requires - Enter your user password or administrator password.`

First, I've confirmed that my user account has administrator privileges by going to Apple --> System Preferences... --> Users & Groups and verifying that the "Current User" has "Admin".

Second, when I enter the administrator password for the Mac, the machine spins for a minute before coming back with a `Failed to obtain administrator privileges` message. I have verified that the administrator password is correct by, again, going into Users & Groups and using it when clicking the "lock" to make changes.

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: When you say you entered the "administrator password," was it your usename's password or another admin-designated user?

Comment: It was the username's password. There are no other admin-designated users, or any users for that matter, on the laptop. Thank you.

Comment: Puzzling... I'd create a fresh user with admin credentials and try it from that account just to see if anything wonky is going on with yours.